# VS2015 Xamarin sample app compiling Error

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I already have

> java version "1.8.0_121"

but still getting this error.

> VS2015 Xamarin Error: Project  cannot build using Android 7.1 (API Level 25 - Nougat) because Your Java version (1.7.0) is too old. You must have at least 1.8 installed

Haven't found any info on line about this error. How do I fix this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the latest JDK 1.8 x64 from here: 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

You will then need to set the path in the tools-options menu.
Have a look at "Additional configuration for Android" from here: http://motzcod.es/post/158155898027/setting-up-vs-2017-for-xamarin-dev

Answer (score 0):

Ken Kosmowski answer's second link helped me I had to change path there. I have attached screenshot for quick viewers
[image]